# Implementing Razorpay orders API in ionic 4 application?

Tags: woocommerce, ionic4, razorpay

I'am building an ecommerce PWA on top of woocommerce REST API with ionic 4. I'm using razorpay for payment. I have successfully integrated payment from client side. But would also like to implement payment using the razorpay orders api using client side. How can i implement this?

Comment: Don't know about razorpay... but isn't there documentation? Did you read it? If yes, edit your question to include what the problem is.

Comment: Already I implemented Razorpay Payment API in Ionic 4 Application.May i know what errors you get. There are some steps to perform in Xcode for taking IOS Build. If you want, then i will share it